# grpcio package installation error- "`_needs_stub` attribute from older version of setuptools", setuptools fully upgraded?

Tags: setuptools, grpcio

Am trying to install tensor flow object detection api manually so that another program of mine can properly run. When installing all the packages needed, grpcio specifically failed, I received the error message below:

`

```
commands.CommandError: We expect a missing '_needs_stub' attribute from older versions of setuptools. Consider upgrading setuptools.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of grpcio
  Moving to /Users/ishaangupta/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/
   from /Users/ishaangupta/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~rpc
  Moving to /Users/ishaangupta/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpcio-1.42.0.dist-info/
   from /Users/ishaangupta/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~rpcio-1.42.0.dist-info
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> grpcio
`
```

I expected grpcio to be setup properly, but...

I tried upgrading setuptools as recommended, using `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and it apparently was already upgraded. Not sure what else to do.

I'm pretty new to programming and am honestly deep into uncharted territory, so any help with a kind explanation would mean a lot!

P.S. I saw a similar question on S.O. but upgrading setuptools seemed to raise another error for them, and I'm not sure what to do if setuptools is working fine... thanks in advance :')